# Particle System null outside start function

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the most confusing unassigned reference bug.

I cache the Particle system variable in the start function, but when I want to use it later, it's null. Nothing interacts with the emitter until after the Debug.Log inside the Activate function. I should also mention that I instantiate the object at runtime.

```cs
[SerializeField] ParticleSystem emitter;
    public event Action<BulletT> OnFire;
    public ParticleSystem Emmitter => emitter;
    void Awake()
    {
        emitter = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        //it's not null
        Debug.Log(emitter);
    }
    
    public void Activate(StatsT userStats)
    {
        //emitter is null, why???
        //also, when I look in the inspector, it's displayed as it exists
        Debug.Log(emitter);

        OnFire?.Invoke(this);
        emitter.Emit(1);
    }
```

Comment: try adding `Debug.Log(emitter, this);` and click on the log message -> does it highlight the correct object? Also to be sure make sure that `Collapse` is disabled in the console

Comment: does the debug line of awake print before activate? ive been recently seeing that a number of method calls to my components awake/start hasnt happened so things are  null, when really they shouldnt be, its like someones flipped a lazy switch and so all the objects arent made at the beginning when you think, but later when codewise it tries to use them...  it didnt use to do this, i assumed id screwed up somewhere and it was something i was doing. But it seems im not alone.  My action in the end was if null then run awake/start and then continue.

Comment: @BugFinder might happen e.g. if the objects are spawned as inactive - e.g. because a prefab is stored as inactive ... for a long time I always assumed `Awake` would get called no matter what and only `Start` is delayed until enabled ... but even `Awake` isn't called if the object is initially inactive ^^

Comment: @derHugo yeah, that would make some sense, because they arent alive to run it, but, when its running update, and hasnt run start or awake yet, something seems off..

Comment: @BugFinder `Activate` here though is not called from this scripts `Update` etc so it might still be the case .. would be a rare one though ^^ Possible that something is spawning the object as inactive, calling `Activate` and then it is set to active .. but that would be quite a bizarre setup

Comment: Yes. I know something is fruity at my end i just havent nailed it down. But i thought I would share with the OP that they aren't alone. And how i have allowed for this circumstance in my own

Comment: @BugFinder I found what was the problem. The object that was holding this script is Instantiated by a different script (in my case, by the Gun object). The problem was that I later called the Activate function on the prefab, not the actual Instance.

Comment: Well done. Glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem. The object that was holding this script is Instantiated by a different script (in my case, by Gun). The problem was that I later called the Activate function on the prefab, not the actual Instance.
How it was:

```cs
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] BulletT bullet;//prefab
    [SerializeField] StatsT _userStats;
    void Awake()
    {
        if (GetComponentInChildren<BulletT>(true) == null)
            Instantiate(bullet, transform.Find("ShootingSpot"));////////
        
    }
    
    //Fired by animation event
    public void Shoot()
    {
        bullet.Activate(_userStats);//I Call on prefab
    }
}
```

Fixed:

```cs
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] BulletT bullet;//prefab before the game starts
    [SerializeField] StatsT _userStats;
    void Awake()
    {
        if (GetComponentInChildren<BulletT>(true) == null)
            bullet = Instantiate(bullet, transform.Find("ShootingSpot"));// Now I assign the instanciated object back to bullet as I don't need to store the object anymore
        
    }
    
    //Fired by animation event
    public void Shoot()
    {
        bullet.Activate(_userStats);//I Call on instanciated object
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).